# How to translate C# events to Delphi

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am porting some kind of code from Visual Studio to Delphi 10.

Wondering how we should translate the following construct:

```
public event PreviewReadyDelegate PreviewReady
    {
        add     { Scheduler.AddOrRemoveEvent(() => { _previewReady += value; }); }
        remove  { Scheduler.AddOrRemoveEvent(() => { _previewReady -= value; }); }
    }
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: There is no such thing as XE10, and I removed the XE tag because that refers to a specific version that I am sure you aren't using.

Comment: ah interference :)

Answer (score 4):

C# [events are multicast delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event). There is no equivalent construct in the Delphi language. You would need to implement your own multicast mechanism or use an existing one from a third party library, for instance that found in [spring4d](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d).